# How to prevent gocd pipeline download maven dependencies on each test run?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, go-cd

When I'm running my tests on gocd, maven downloads dependencies every time.

I am thinking about the steps below. But i need to know location of folder the dependencies are downloaded.

- Using two pipelines.
- One for downloading dependencies and create an artifact for it. I'm planning to run it for one time.
- Second for running tests. It took the artifacts from the other pipeline and run tests directly.

Is that a way prevent to download the dependencies every time?

Answer (score 0):

GoCD doesn't do anything specifically to download the dependencies each time. The `mvn` command you run as part of your build does it.

Few reasons why this might happen:

1. **Elastic Agents**: If the agents are containers that are decommissioned after the build, you can run into this problem. Consider mounting a shared volume on the path `/var/go/.m2` on the agent to re-use the cache across runs. The ways to do that, is beyond the scope of this answer though.
2. **Housekeeping scripts**: Clearing `/var/go/.m2` or more generally `~/.m2` on the agents boxes is more common than I would like to admit. This can happen in some infrastructure / teams, where they have a script to clear off these dependencies to save disk space. You might want to check with your Ops team if something like this exist in your infrastructure.